# How to implement about getting current user information from server when using spring security while i access user information from android client

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

- This is the JSON that I returned after logging in:

  ```
   {
    "access_token":"41208e01a-f26c-4167-9fc9-d16730022056",
     "token_type": "bearer",
     "refresh_token": "3808e00a-896c-8067-18c9-736730022032",
     "expires_in": 25348,
     "scope": "read write",
     "jti": "6f08e00a-d26c-4067-8fc9-c16730022028"
    }
  ```
- I want to get current user information by using this `url:https://localhost:8080/user/getuserinfo?access_token=41208e01a-f26c-4167-9fc9-d16730022056` from android client,i meant that how to implement requirement on server and this is my [Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492506/how-can-i-use-spring-security-oauth2-to-realize-the-purpose-about-redirecting)

Answer (score 0):

I change my spring SecurityConfig,here is used to processing some authorizeUrls:

```
@Configuration
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//doing jdbc Authentication
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
super.configure(auth);
}
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ClientSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.antMatcher("/mobile/**")
  .formLogin().loginPage("/client/login")
  .loginProcessingUrl("/oauth/login")
  .successHandler(clientLoginSuccessHandler).permitAll()
  .and()
  .logout()
  .logoutSuccessHandler(clientLogoutSuccessHandler)
  .logoutUrl("/client/logout")
  .logoutSuccessUrl("/client/login")
  .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
}
@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {          
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.regexMatcher("/((?!api).)*")
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/web/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/oauth/login")
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler)
            .logoutUrl("/web/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/web/login")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
  }
 }
}
```

and add ResourceServerConfig for handle token validation issues：

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
TokenStore tokenStore;

@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**").//
            and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**",).authenticated();
}

@Override
public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
    resources.resourceId("openid").tokenStore(tokenStore);
}


}
```

finally,build a request with a request header

```
"Authorization:Bearer <access_token>"
```